# ASP.NET Core Microsoft Identity sign out "The scheme field is required."

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-web

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 with Azure AD authentication.

I created a new template web app and sign in and sign out with Azure AD work great.

But when I copied the relevant code in `Startup.cs` and `appsettings.json` from the template web app into another web app, I'm getting a 400 error response when I click the Sign Out link to /MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut

```
["The scheme field is required."]
```

in `Startup.cs`, I've added:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

and

```
services.AddRazorPages()
             .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

I've compared the requests in the template web app that works and the other web app that doesn't, and I can't see any difference in the request headers to /MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut.

[image: Request headers to /MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut]

What "scheme" am I missing?

Comment: Interesting. :) And there is no exception logged with a helpful stack trace? Because the error message seems to indicates that a `RequiredAttribute` is not satisfied on a `scheme` property of some input model, so validation fails, which would further indicate that some action consuming that model is not executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @Leaky's pointer about looking at the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` `SignOut()` [source code](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs), I changed the Sign Out URL structure to explicitly include the `scheme` parameter like this:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var parms = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "scheme", OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme }
    };
    <a asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut" 
       asp-all-route-data="parms">
        Sign out
    </a>
}
```

Now when I hover my mouse over the link, instead of:

`https://localhost:44350/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut`

The sign out link looks like this:

`https://localhost:44350/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut/OpenIdConnect`

And the full sign out works without error.

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code of `Microsoft.Identity.Web` ([see here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web)) and MVC, and I think the only reasonable explanation is that you have the [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) C# 8 feature enabled in your second project.

I was able to reproduce the error when I enabled nullables.

What is happening is that the `SignOut` action has the following attributes and signature:

```csharp
// From Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/AccountController.cs
// See: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs

/// <summary>
/// Handles the user sign-out.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scheme">Authentication scheme.</param>
/// <returns>Sign out result.</returns>
[HttpGet("{scheme?}")]
public IActionResult SignOut([FromRoute] string scheme)
{
   ...
}
```

When you have nullables enabled, this produces the error you observed, because the `scheme` in the method signature is not optional anymore. The issue is similar to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22656).

My suspicion is that while nullable support was added to ASP.NET Core and (I suppose) most of its components in 2020, `Microsoft.Identity.Web` did not get the same treatment (it's actually completely separate from ASP.NET Core; it's part of [AzureAD](https://github.com/AzureAD).

*What is perhaps more interesting is that why don't the other account actions (having a similar signature) lead to the same error. I don't use neither nullables, nor Microsoft.Identity.Web, so I don't have information pertaining to this.*

But of course let me know if I'm wrong, and you don't have nullables enabled. :)

Comment: Project level nullable is disabled `<Nullable>disable</Nullable>`.

Comment: This got me pointed in the right direction with the Identity source code and required `scheme` param.